# can't seem to get php working in MAMP

Tags: php, html, mamp

I'm trying to learn php and step one is getting php working in some capacity. I'm attempting to use MAMP but I'm having some trouble.

Specifically: if I create a file with the below code and save it as index.html in MAMP's "Document Root" directory, I get a blank page when pointing my browser at http://localhost:8888/index.html.

Code:

```
<html>
<body>

    <?php
    echo "Hello World!";
    ?>

</body>
</head>
```

Alternatively, if I put a bit of php into its own file (say test.php) and then point my browser at this file, it just displays the full text of the file in the browser.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You must save a file with php inside it with a .php extension. So you would need to name it `index.php` instead of `index.html`.

Comment: Is you apache configured to interpret .html files with php?

Comment: @JosephTorraca Lord. I knew it would be something goofy like that. Thanks for your help. If you like, submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must save a file with PHP inside it with a .php extension. So you would need to name it `index.php` instead of `index.html`. Simple fix.

Answer (score 12):

I had the similar issue.

Make a new file in TextWrangler or Komodo, or whatever, and add the folllowing code:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

You're going to save the file as .htaccess (with the dot in the front; this is the file name). 
Save it in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs. This is the same place you'll save your php and html files. This .htaccess will be an invisible file; you will not see it in Finder, tho you can if you cd to it in Terminal, or searching w/in Finder and choosing the File Visibility type under Kind.

Now try going to localhost:8888/ and you should see all of the available files there. And with this newly created .htaccess file, you can now embed php inside an html file too.

Comment: If you have MAMP Pro, you can make this change so that it affects *all* your hosts/sites by editing the template here: **File** > **Edit Template** > **Apache** > **httpd.conf** and pasting those two lines into that file down inside the `<IfModule mime_module>` tags (about 3/4 of the way to the bottom). You will see similar `AddHandler` statements in there.

Answer (score 7):

In MAMP, edit  the file:

/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf

and then search for '#AddHandler type-map' (exclude quotes).  Below that, add,

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html

Save the file and stop and re-start MAMP.  Php parsing will occur in files ending with the extensions: .php and .html.

Comment: Adding ".html" to the end of the "AddType application/x-httpd-php .php" line in httpd.conf OR renaming the file from index.html to index.php worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

So, this just worked for me:

instead of having:

MAMP/htdocs/folder-that-contains-all-files/

put all your files directly in the htdocs folder!

so:

MAMP/htdocs/all your files including index.php etc.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Modifying /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf

searching for #AddHandler type-map

and inserting AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html

worked for me.